# drawing objects on grid with empty positions

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

I would like to regularly space objects over a figure, but have some of the grid positions empty. Method 1 below works, but makes it hard to leave grid positions empty (would need some complicated if logic i guess). Method 2 (trying to use a foreach over coordinates and then scaling and offsetting those coordinates onto my grid) does not work, i get `! Dimension too large. <recently read> \pgfmath@x [...]. I can't work with sizes bigger than about 19 feet.` errors. How do i make this work?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\step}
\setlength{\step}{2.618cm}

\def\cols{14}
\def\rows{14}
\def\side{4\step}
\def\sep{1\step}

\def\half{0.5*\side}
\def\bottom{0}
\def\left{0}

\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[draw,color=black!30]
    
% grid
\draw[step=\step, line width=3pt] (0cm,0cm) grid (\step*\cols,\step*\rows);

% method 1
\foreach \y in {0,...,2}{%
    \foreach \x in {0,...,2}{%
        \coordinate (m) at (
            \left+\half+\x*\side+\x*\sep,
            \bottom+\half+\y*\side+\y*\sep
        );
        
        \draw[fill=black] (m) circle (21.5mm);
        \draw[fill=white] (m) circle (11.5mm);
        \draw[fill=black] (m) circle (1.5mm);
    }
};


% method 2
\foreach \xy in {(0,0),(1,1),(2,0)}{%
    \path let \p1 = \xy in coordinate (m2) at (
        \left+\half+\x1*\side,
        \bottom+\half+\y1*\side
    );
    
    \draw[fill=black] (m2) circle (21.5mm);
    \draw[fill=white] (m2) circle (11.5mm);
    \draw[fill=black] (m2) circle (1.5mm);
};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SE!!

I don't understand what you're trying to do and I think that it probably will be better ways to scale and offset the objects.

Anyway, that said, you can easily modify your method 2 as follows:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\newlength{\step}
\setlength{\step}{2.618cm}

\def\cols{14}
\def\rows{14}
\def\side{4\step}
\def\sep{1\step}
\def\half{0.5*\side}
\def\bottom{0}
\def\left{0}

\begin{tikzpicture}[draw,color=black!30]
% grid
\draw[step=\step, line width=3pt] (0cm,0cm) grid (\step*\cols,\step*\rows);
% method 2 modified
\foreach \x/\y in {0/0,1/1,2/0} {%
    \draw[fill=black] (\left+\half+\x*\side,\bottom+\half+\y*\side) circle (21.5mm);
    \draw[fill=white] (\left+\half+\x*\side,\bottom+\half+\y*\side) circle (11.5mm);
    \draw[fill=black] (\left+\half+\x*\side,\bottom+\half+\y*\side) circle  (1.5mm);
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Your answer does what i needed, and also helped me phrase the problem better: I needed a way to loop over an array of tuples, and this / syntax allows that. Nice!